# Run rest API tests from docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, unit-testing, docker-compose

I'm trying to implement tests in my node.js project. I decided to use mocha / chai / chai-http to test my rest API.

I just have 1 simple file in my test folder:

**movie.ts:**

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
let app = require('../app');
chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);
declare var process : {
  env: {
    API_KEY: string
  }
}

describe('/GET movies', () => {
  it('it should GET all the movies', (done) => {
    chai.request(app)
        .get('/v1/movies')
        .set("Authorization", process.env.API_KEY)
        .end((err, res) => {
              res.should.have.status(200);
              res.body.should.be.a('array');
          done();
        });
  });
});
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

Docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        env_file: ./.env
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
            MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
        ports:
            - $MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT
        volumes:
            - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - mysql_config:/etc/mysql
            - ./sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 8080:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOSTS: mariadb
    web:
        build: .
        env_file: ./.env
        command: npm start
        volumes: 
            - .:/app/
            - /app/node_modules
        ports:
            - $NODE_LOCAL_PORT:$NODE_DOCKER_PORT
        depends_on: 
            - mariadb
        environment: 
            MYSQL_HOST: mariadb
    web-tests:
        image: hypescript_web
        command: npm test
        environment: 
            MYSQL_HOST: mariadb
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
            - web
volumes:
    mysql:
    mysql_config:
```

This test is working but I have 2 problems when I run it during `docker compose up` cmd.

As you can see I created another container just for the test and I'm not sure if it's the best practice to test my API. `web-tests` container uses my node.js image built in the docker compose so if I don't have the image already built in my machine I have to comment all my web-tests services and when the image is built then I can uncomment web-tests and I can use it to run mocha tests.

The 2nd problem is that I need to set a timeout to run my test (e.g after 10 seconds) because I build my database at the same time and the first time I'll get database errors because the tests are running and the database init isn't finished. I tried to add a timeout to mocha in the `package.json` but the timeout is ignored.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L app.ts",
    "debug": "export DEBUG=* && npm run start",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000 -r ts-node/register test/**/*.ts"
  }
```

I think I'm doing something wrong because it's very heavy to run my API tests.
I'd like to runs my tests without comment / uncomment at the first run and add a timeout.
How do you do to runs your API tests in docker ?

Comment: Can you run your API tests outside of Docker; `chai.request(\`http://localhost:${process.env.NODE_LOCAL_PORT}\`).get()...`?

Comment: @DavidMaze if I run `npm test` outside docker I got this error `Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000` because the container use this address

Comment: @DavidMaze if I remove the `app` variable from my test and replacing by `http://localhost:3000` I can run my test outside of docker

Comment: So for API tests it's better run our tests outside docker ?

Comment: "Better" is definitely subjective; but the test code isn't something you'd ordinarily want to package with your application, and API calls would normally be coming from "outside Docker", so it makes sense to me here.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ok thanks. I thought we need to package the test for CI/CD to stop the deployment if the tests fail

Comment: To address your first issue (having a separate test container): _in general_ I recommend using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/language/java/run-tests/#multi-stage-dockerfile-for-testing). The test code won't be included in the final image of your API, but your build will be rejected if any tests fail. I personally love being able to do 'everything' in a single Dockerfile.

I am not sure if this would fit your type of tests (which require a running database) - but theoretically your process _could_ be to only build (+test) your API once you brought the database `up`.